# TFS 2010 migration to another server questions

Tags: migration, team-foundation-server

I have already built the new server, installed TFS, and migrated the databases and am working on making sure everything is working. I will need to do the DB migration again in the future when I cutover.

Am I able to bring over just the DefaultCollection database at this point again since the ReportServer, Tfs_Configuration and Tfs_Warehouse shouldn't change I think?

I was fighting with permissions and ended up adding the Windows service account to the TFS console administrators which got everything working. I am guessing though that this isn't best practice? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move only the Collection databases, you **must** move the Configuration DB also!
Report Server DB is important only if you customized some reports.
Wharehouse can be rebuilt from scratch.

The [Move Team Foundation Server from One Environment to Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883(v=vs.100).aspx) page can help you understand of what a move implies.

You can use "tfconfig setup uninstall:all" to unconfigure your server. Then delete the existing databses to reset for the next migration...

Comment: I have already moved all the DB once so right now I have a working copy of TFS at the time of the backup. Since then time has passed and people have continued to work on the old server. I have a date scheduled to cutover and need to update the new one. At this point can I just move the collection since I already moved and used the config DB?

Comment: No, unless you detach the Collection (using TFS Admin Console or the TFSConfig command) from old server, backup and restore the DB and then you reattach the collection on the new server.
A Collection DB is not self-contained, the Configuration DB is always required, unless you do the detach/attach from TFS (not on SQL!).

Comment: That stinks, it was kinda a pain to get things working after moving stuff. I guess I will just need to plan a bigger window of time to get things working after the move.

Comment: In my experience the Collection detach/attach operations are fast even for big databases. After the Collection is detached, you can even detach the DB from SQL and with a bit of care copy the files over to the new servers. Caveat 1: SQL permissions to database. Caveat 2: detach the Collection on the target server before overwriting.